# Recreate Medium's Image Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to recreate the image zoom effect that Medium uses when you click an image and want to see its larger version.

Here's an example .gif of it.
[image: Here's an example .gif of it.]

I've tried multiple ways, with jQuery CSS transforms, and so on - but I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

How could I recreate an effect like this?

Comment: And what trouble are you having exactly?

Comment: @JulienBernu Here's a JSFiddle of what I have so far. Check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/mz103/a9hfkpvL/

Comment: @JulienBernu I'm mainly having trouble making it dynamic, and having the image zoom out from its current location to the center of the page.

Comment: @JulienBernu Basically I want the div to teleport to the current image's location, and then scale to the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom in and out effect can be achieved using CSS transform property. Basically you translate the image to the window center, then scale the image. To zoom out, just remove the transform value.

Actually there is an open-sourced library of Medium's image zoom called [zoom.js](https://github.com/fat/zoom.js) using jQuery. I also implemented a similar library [Zooming](https://github.com/kingdido999/zooming) with pure JavaScript.